# Custom function in excel that looks at a calculated field and shows you the equation in readable format

Tags: vba, excel

For example, if I had the excel formula

```
=sum(b2:b6)*exp(c2)
```

Column `B` being `Sales` and column `C` being `Growth`

I'd like it to show something like this:

> ΣSales * e^Growth

(Basically so it looks readable and easily tells you what is going on in your excel formula)

Anyone know of a function/macro that is out there that does this currently, or if not, how would you go about creating one of these functions? I'm thinking some kind of add-on needs to be installed in excel first?

Comment: a) I know of nothing that currently does this b) I would start by building a cross-reference table of [every Excel function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-functions-alphabetical-A04384E2-9D24-446A-AC5C-592C9CC55FE6) and the *'readable'* phrase I would use to refer to it.

Comment: You can look at DataTables in Excel. Formulas in these can use the column headers instead of cell references.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the [Excel Equation Editor](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Use-Equation-Editor-in-Excel-771c7a8b-4b3d-4ab8-982a-8ab22f1212ce#)

Go to the **Insert** tab and touch **Object** then pick the Editor:

[image]

After some practice you will be able to generate decent equations.